# What are the names of 8 Prahars of a day?

Tags: practice, time

Many villagers do Naama Sankirtana in their villages, decorating a Naama Mandapa and performs the Naama Sankirtana very pleasantly for 24 hours = Ashtha Prahari (1 Prahari = 3 hrs). So a full day is divided into to 8 parts.

My questions

What is the meaning of Prahari?

What are the names of 8 Prahars of a day?

What are the significance of each Prahari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Prahara is one type of time measure. The full day is divided into eight parts.

According to Srimad Bhagvata Purana:

> लघूनि वै समाम्नाता दश पञ्च च नाडिका । 
>  ते द्वे मुहूर्तः **प्रहरः**
>   षड्यामः सप्त वा नृणाम् ॥[**SB 3.11.8**](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n283/mode/2up)   ॥ Page 279
>
> laghūni vai samāmnātā daśa pañca ca nāḍikā 
>  te dve muhūrtaḥ
>   **praharaḥ** ṣaḍ yāmaḥ sapta vā nṛṇām
>
> Six or seven Nadikas make one Prahara of men. It is also called Yama.
>
> ---
>
> यामाश्चत्वारश्चत्वारो मर्त्यानामहनी उभे।
>   पक्षः पञ्चदशाहानि शुक्लः कृष्णश्च मानद ॥ 3.11.10||
>
> [SB 3.11.10](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/11/10/)
>   It is calculated that **there are four praharas, which are also called yāmas, in the day and four in the night of the human being.** Similarly, fifteen days and nights are a fortnight, and there are two fortnights, white and black, in a month

We can read  more about the measurement of time uptil Prahara in verse no. 5-8 of same chapter of Bhagavad Purana.

<sup>I recommend to refer Panchanga to have complete and reliable information about Prahara and Muhurta.</sup>

The names of four Praharas of the Day are as follows:

1. pUrvAnha (पूर्वान्ह)
2. madhyAnha (मध्यान्ह)
3. aparAnha (अपरान्ह)
4. sayAnha​ or sAyaMkAla (सयान्ह​ or सायंकाल)

And the Night is considered to be consisting the time of three prahara called

- triyAmA (त्रियामा) and remaining
- uShA (उषा)

Though some narrates the the four Praharas of Night as follows (but I have not find reliable source to this):

5. pradoSha (प्रदोष)
6. (निशिथ)
7. triyAmA (त्रियामा)
8. uShA (उषा)

Talking about significance of each Prahara, it is believed that there is a specific time to sing particular Raga i.e Some [ragas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raga) are prescribed to be performed at a particular prahara. And there is also significance of performing worship in specified Prahara.

<sup>[1]: [Gauravshali Bhartiya Kalaganana](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8M2zBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT5&pg=PT33#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 33.</sup>